# StackOv, an open-source SwiftUI Stack Overflow client

Tags: app, stackoverflow, iphone, mac-os-x, swift

#### About:

I'd made this app on my personal hackathon  - about 10 days.
I hope you'll like it.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

[image]

#### Download / Install:

- ‍ [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/stackov/id1511838391)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/surfstudio/StackOv)

#### Platform:

Available for iOS, iPadOS, and Mac OS.